# mongoose schema not sending correct address details

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

was wondering if someone had an of how I can develop a schema for the following model below, all fields are required.

Data I want captured
{
"name": "The Shop",
"address": {
"line_one":"123 Joe Blogs Ave",
"line_two":"District 1",
"city":"Random city",
"postcode/zip":"AB12 3BJ"
},
"coverImage":"imageURL",
"rating": 4.5
}

```
    const placeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    address: {
      line_one: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      line_two: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      postcode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  },
  coverImage: {
    type: String,
    rating: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
    },
  },
});
```

When posting the data  I only find returned the name, coverimage, _id and __v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use subdocuments for this, or Nested Schemas:
So basically for nested Objects you define another Schema, and then tell the main schema that the field is of type subschema

````js
const addressSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    line_one: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    line_two: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    postcode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

const placeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        address: {
            type: addressSchema,
            required: true
        }
    },
    coverImage: {
        type: String,
        rating: {
            type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128,
        },
    },
});
```
````

Comment: Thanks max! Will give that a go!